# Crucible after restore fails in Jira

Tags: atlassian-crucible

1. I install and user Crucible+FishEye on http://mydomen:8060
2. work several month - all works, integration with jira was worked.
3. I create http://crucible.mydomain (in other physic server) - with nginx proxy on localhost:8060, install Crucible+FishEye and restore from backup.

And now i get erro in jira tasks Source and Rewiev tab:

```
This list of reviews may be incomplete, as errors occurred retrieving data from the following repositories:

Request to http://mydomen:8060/ failed: Error in remote call to 'mydomen' (http://crucible1.mydomen) [AbstractRestCommand{path='rest-service/search-v1/reviews', params={maxReturn=50, term=XM-911}, methodType=GET}] : Received status code 404 (Not Found)
Request to http://crucible.mydomain/ failed: Error in remote call to 'Crucible+FishEye' (http://mydomen:8060) [AbstractRestCommand{path='rest-service/search-v1/reviews', params={maxReturn=50, term=XM-911}, methodType=GET}] : The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 10000 ms
```

Why it try connected on http://mydomen:8060 ??
In my Crucible > Administration > Global settings > Server > HTTP Bind=crucible.mydomain

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: I need recreate Application links in http://jira.mydomen/plugins/servlet/applinks/listApplicationLinks